# r function list all parameters including ellipses

Tags: r

Is there any ways to list all parameters including ellipses(additional parameters with three dots) of R function? For example,I want to know "qplot" function's parameters,the only way I found is args(qplot),which result

```
> args(qplot)
function (x, y = NULL, ..., data, facets = NULL, margins = FALSE, 
    geom = "auto", xlim = c(NA, NA), ylim = c(NA, NA), log = "", 
    main = NULL, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), 
    asp = NA, stat = NULL, position = NULL)
```

But I really want to know what additional parameters the three dots represents can pass into this function.for example,the "shape" parameter.

Comment: You should type `> qplot` or `> ?qplot` to get more info. The `> qplot` will provide you code for the function where you can find details and `>?qplot` will provide you documentation for the function.

Comment: I know how to use help function.However this doesn't list all available parameters that is truly acceptable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What additional parameters can be used and how they get processed depends on the function. That’s the whole point of the ellipsis. In my answer below I give the example for `qplot`.

Comment: Okay,I have seen your reply below.Then I just learn that we don't have a function,which can directly display available additional parameters that don't list when I use args function,such as shape,size,fill.Or I should consider all parameters are within .all_aesthetics.

Answer (score 1):

The three dot ellipsis `...` refer to any number of function arguments that get processes/passed on within the function body.
    For example, in the case of `qplot`, the function body (which you can see if you execute `qplot`) reveals that any *additional* function arguments will be used as additional aesthetic specifications.

The relevant lines are:

```
arguments <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
env <- parent.frame()
aesthetics <- compact(arguments[.all_aesthetics])
```

where

```
.all_aesthetics <- c("adj", "alpha", "angle", "bg", "cex", "col", "color",
    "colour", "fg", "fill", "group", "hjust", "label", "linetype", "lower",
    "lty", "lwd", "max", "middle", "min", "pch", "radius", "sample", "shape",
    "size", "srt", "upper", "vjust", "weight", "width", "x", "xend", "xmax",
    "xmin", "xintercept", "y", "yend", "ymax", "ymin", "yintercept", "z")
```

The definition of `.all_aesthetics` can be found [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/aes.r).

Comment: @mt1022 If I understood OP correctly, this was a `qplot` specific question: *"For example,I want to know "qplot" function's parameters,[...]"*. The first sentence of my answer is a generally valid statement on the role of `...`, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I might misunderstand the OP. I deleted that comment.